# How to activate a pin in Assembler?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

I want to activate the 23 pin to light an LED

[image]

```
      ; Reset Vector
      rjmp   Start
      
Start:  
      ldi r16, 0x00     ;Cargar el registro de trabajo 16 al valor 0
      out DDRB, r16         ;Asignar al puerto B el valor del registro 16
      ldi r16, 0xFF     ;Carga el registro de trabajo 16, el valor FF
      out DDRC, r16     ;Asignar al puerto C el valor del registro 16
      
Loop:
      in r16, PINB      ;Lee puerto B
      out PORTC, r16        ;Escribe en puerto C lo leído
      ldi PORTC, 1
      rjmp Loop
```

Comment: What chip are you programming for?

Comment: The schematic says ATmega328P.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable PC0 (pin 23) output then you need to set bit #0 in both `DDRC` (which enables output driver at the pin) and `PORTC` (which selects high output level).
You can either use `OUT` command to write 8bit value to an I/O register:

```
ldi r16, 0x01
out PORTC, r16
out DDRC, r16
```

or you can use `sbi` instruction to set a bit in one of first 32 I/O registers:

```
sbi PORTC, 0
sbi DDRC, 0
```